# JQuery UI Autocomplete Search Results do not display

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

arrayI am getting no search results from my mysql database using php.

**PHP Code:**

```
require_once "connectmysql.php";
$belongsto=$current_user->businessname;
$q = trim(strip_tags($_GET["term"]));
if (!$q) return;
$sql = "select clientname as value from zb_clients where clientname LIKE '%".$q."%' AND belongsto='".$belongsto."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
    $row_set[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($row_set);
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    //autocomplete
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: "../searchclient.php",
        minLength: 1,
    });             

});
</script>
```

**Input Field:**

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for Business Name" />
```

I believe the php code is correct. If I run the php code on its own and use 
`/searchclient.php?term=a`

as an example, it returns the results that I want in an array.

e.g. `[{"value":"Hello World"},{"value":"East Meets West JV"}]`.

If I replace the Jquery line

`source: "../searchclient.php",`

with

`source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ],`

then the automocomplete works with that source. So there must be an issue with the array passing back into JQuery.

I cant quite put my finger on it. Am I missing something crucial?

Ive tried debugging with firebug but its not returning any errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Edited PHP Code:**

```
require_once "connectmysql.php";
$belongsto=$current_user->businessname;
$q = $_GET["term"];
if (!$q) return;
$sql = "select clientname as value, idzb_clients as id from zb_clients where clientname LIKE '%".$q."%' AND belongsto='".$belongsto."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row['id']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id']));
    $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
    $row['label']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
    $row_set[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($row_set);
```

Comment: My debug.log is saying PHP Notice:  Undefined index: term in C:\path. So must be an issue with the line `$q = $_GET["term"];` any ideas why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went down the AJAX route and this seemed to work:

**HTML**

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "../searchclient.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        q: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        response( data );
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 1
});
```

**SEARCHCLIENT.PHP**

```
<?php

require_once "connectmysql.php";
$belongsto = $current_user->businessname;
$q = $_GET['q'];
$sql = "select clientname as value, idzb_clients as id, has_ledger_setup from zb_clients where clientname LIKE '%".$q."%' AND belongsto='".$belongsto."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row['id'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id']));
    $row['value'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
    $row['label'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
    $row_set[] = $row;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($row_set);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
    source: "../searchclient.php",
    minLength: 1,
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + item.value + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: I just tried this and no it does not work. It's as if the data is not returning from the php back into jquery.

Comment: yes, as I mentioned, it works when the source is hardcoded into the JQuery. However it does not work when I want to query the database using php e.g. source: /searchclient.php, even though the output of the php file is `[{"value":"Hello World"},{"value":"East Meets West JV"}]`. So I know the searchclient.php is outputting the correct data, but its not returning it back into jquery.

Comment: If I go directly to localhost:9080/searchclient.php/?term=e then the data outputs `[{"value":"Hello World","id":"1","label":"Hello World"},{"value":"East Meets West JV","id":"2","label":"East Meets West JV"}]`. See updated PHP Code, I added ID & Label.

Comment: can you put your code on any server. from there i can check it