# jQuery UI Autocomplete Display "No search results"

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui

I want to display suggestions from mysql database using jQuery UI Autocomplete

I have following form

```
 <form action="search.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search-input">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
 </form>
```

search.php

```
    <?php 
require_once 'db.php';

$a = array();

    if (isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search'])) {
        $search_param = trim($_POST['search']);

        $slct_search = $db->prepare("SELECT student_name FROM student_details WHERE student_name LIKE ?") or die($db->error);
        $slct_search->bind_param('s', $search_param);
        $slct_search->execute();        
        $res = $slct_search->get_result();  
        if($res->num_rows) {            
            while ($result = $res->fetch_object()) {
                $a[] = $result->student_name;
            }
            echo json_encode($a);
        } else {
            echo 'OOPS we had a problem';
        }   
    }
?>
```

The search.php working fine. it returns

> ["ravi","ravi"]

JS Code

```
    $(function() {
      $("#search-input").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2
      }); 
    });
```

The Problem is when I start type in text box immediately displayed

> No search results.

i also tried [JQuery UI Autocomplete Search Results do not display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879725/jquery-ui-autocomplete-search-results-do-not-display)

Comment: please any one answer with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
  <form action="" method="">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search-input" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
        <div id="empty-message"></div>
  </form>
```

Now **search.php**

```
    $searchTerm = trim($_GET['term']);

    $query = $db->query("SELECT student_name FROM student_details WHERE student_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY student_name ASC");


    while ($row = $query->fetch_object()) {
        $data[] = $row->student_name;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
```

jquery ui autocomplete only working with $_GET

So i am using $_GET['term'], See below Picture

[image]

**JS code**

```
$('#search-input').autocomplete({
    source: 'search.php',
    minLength: 2,
    response: function(event, ui) {
        // ui.content is the array that's about to be sent to the response callback.
        if (ui.content.length === 0) {
            $("#empty-message").text("No results found");
        } else {
            $("#empty-message").empty();
        }
    }
});
```